# Getting ATI Driver To Work?

Tags: graphics, radeon, hybrid-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5450 + Integrated Intel HD to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103126/how-do-i-get-ati-mobility-radeon-hd-5450-integrated-intel-hd-to-work)

I have Linux 12.04 LTS installed on my HPDV7T laptop (dual booted with windows 7).

My laptop specs are: 
 -Intel Core i7 2620M 2.7 Ghz Dual Core processor
 -Radeon 6770m graphics card
 -It is switchable graphics
 -12 GB ram

I've been trying to get catalyst control center to run, but it has this error:

Initialization error:

There was a problem initializing Catalyst Control Center Linux edition.
It could be caused by the following.

No ATI graphics driver is installed, or the ATI driver is not functioning
properly. Please install the ATI driver appropriate for you ATI hardware,
or configure using aticonfig.

Can anyone help? This is the very first time I've used linux, so detailed instructions would be nice. (I do know how to get to the terminal though. And change directory in terminal)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) will help you. It has detailed instructions for the installation process and you can seek further help there. As for the error you are experiencing did you do the initial Xserver config via the command in terminal `sudo aticonfig --initial -f`
 ?

I hope that helps. By the way I myself own a  HP Sandy bridge laptop with discrete 6xx Radeon card. I tried installing the drivers and everything works fine, but when I try to switch from discrete to HD 3000 unity does not load after the reboot. It seems that the Intel card has some problem with Unity/Compiz at start up if the discrete card is enabled. This problem is described on the last pages of the above thread.(You can try and see if it works for you). Good luck.